# Why are those modules being loaded in an ASP.NET web project?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web project (not website) and I don't understand why all these modules are being created and loaded.

I thought that with a web project it would all compile to a single .DLL. Is this correct, and what is happening here?

```
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_fwtnlvuq.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_vb8hmtmg.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_v-nkuwgl.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_wn_uucrw.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_ngd_8nhu.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_8keebrhe.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_ohg9e50r.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_yhmgvhum.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_4qltywkk.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_1nml5ezc.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_cdju8bdk.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_xhugloto.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_rkqqzc0u.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_-vfyn7ik.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reviewstat_20\c147e006\64781866\App_Web_cthyzgij.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are temporary assemblies generated by the ASP.NET runtime after compiling each ASPX page. It's done at runtime, automatically and shouldn't be subject of any concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The modules you see loading are not from your .cs files, but from .aspx/.ascx/etc files that are compiled on appdomain startup. All of your .cs files are compiled into a single DLL (one per project).